# Laptop won't even start fans, new RAM upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

Recently tried to upgrade my laptop's stock ram with something with a little more capacity. I learned that my Satellite C55-B5299 could have 8GB max, so thats what I got.

- Old Ram: Samsung PC3L-12800s-11-13-c3 DDR3 (2GB)
- New Ram: Kingston PC3-12800 cl11 DDR3 (8GB)

When I put in the new Ram, the laptop's light (by the power button) does one long flash, and that is it. No fan, nothing. Nothing will happen on screen.

The old ram will still boot perfectly every time.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your old RAM is PC3L, which is low voltage RAM that runs at 1.35v. The new RAM you got is PC3, which is regular voltage that runs at 1.5v. You just need to return your new Kingston PC3 RAM, and get a set of PC3L.